# Toggle through elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a list of `<input type="text">`-fields. I have found and stored them in a variable like so `var x = $('#id').find('input').css('type', 'text')`. So x is the array with all the input fields. I would like to toggle through the elements when I press ENTER. If the last input field is active I'll want to return to the first when ENTER is pressed.

If the user clicks on the 3rd input field of 5, then the toggle should continue from the 3rd input field and toggle through the rest until it starts over again.

Right now I have a `console.log()` statement that fires when ENTER is pressed (it also works when the input field(s) are acrive).

How do I do it? Is more info needed? Or do you follow the problem?

Comment: Show some more code! [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) is a good place to do that!

Comment: can you share a html sample

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
var $inputs = $('#myid input:text');
$inputs.keyup(function (e) {
    if (e.which == 13) {
        var idx = $inputs.index(this);
        var $next = idx == $inputs.length - 1 ? $inputs.first() : $inputs.eq(idx + 1);
        $next.focus()
    }
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/K3LEt/)

Comment: I can sort of understand what is happening. For some reason the $next variable does not change when ENTER is pressed. But the rest seems good. I'll stay on this track for the time being.

Comment: @Molle sorry what is the problem?